# How to make 'x lives left'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have 5 lives when playing a game.
life = '-----'

Each time I die, it becomes

life = 'x----', then life = 'xx---' and so on

At the beginning of the game, it asks the user how many lives they want.

I have no idea how to make that..
Anyone know?

Comment: which part is causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the number of lives left in `lives`, and the maximum number of lives in `MAX_LIVES`. Then you just do this:

```
life = 'X' * (MAX_LIVES - lives) + '-' * lives
```

You're better off not storing numeric information as strings, which forces you to need to parse it back to numbers at some point, and can lead to a whole slew of hard-to-fix bugs. Store numeric values as numbers and transform them for display when needed.

Another method is to use the `format` method for strings:

```
'{0:X<{1}}'.format('-' * lives, MAX_LIVES)
```

This means "take the first parameter, and pad it on the right with `'X'` characters until it's the width specified in the second parameter."

Answer (score 0):

You could use two counters, one for lives remaining and one for lives lost:

```
startLives = 5
livesLost = 0
livesRemaining = 5

life = "-----"

def loseLife():
    livesLost += 1
    livesRemaining -= 1

def printLifeCounter:
    life = 'x' * livesLost + '-' * livesRemaining
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beggining:

```
life = n * "-" # n - number of lives user entered
```

And call dieonce whenever user loses a life:

```
def dieonce(left_lives):
  return ((N-left_lives) * "x") + (left_lives * "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to what some are saying. If you need to build this string for display anyway, there's not necessarily much advantage to storing a numeric value as well.

```
>>> numlives = 5
>>> life = '-' * numlives
>>> life = 'x' + life[:-1]
>>> life
'x----'
>>> life = 'x' + life[:-1]
>>> life
'xx---'
>>> life = 'x' + life[:-1]
>>> life
'xxx--'
>>> life = 'x' + life[:-1]
>>> life
'xxxx-'
>>> life = 'x' + life[:-1]
>>> life
'xxxxx'
```

When `life[-1] == 'x'` you are dead

```
>>> life[-1]
'x'
```